# Linux log file structure change for usage with kst

Tags: sed, awk, grep, cut, text-formatting

My file (tcp dump from networked sensors) has this shape:

```
20:06:57.049686 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 26871, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 68)
    e108-193.eduroam.tugraz.ac.at.34225 > e158-093.eduroam.tugraz.ac.at.personal-agent: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 40
    0x0000:  4500 0044 68f7 4000 4011 25c7 8083 d0bf  E..Dh.@.@.%.....
    0x0010:  8083 da24 85b1 15b3 0030 1e8b 3132 3033  ...$.....0..1203
    0x0020:  3132 2e37 3836 3036 2c20 332c 2020 2030  12.78606,.3,...0
    0x0030:  2e31 3533 2c20 2d30 2e31 3533 2c20 2039  .153,.-0.153,..9
    0x0040:  2e39 3630                                .960
20:06:57.113591 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 26872, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 68)
    e108-193.eduroam.tugraz.ac.at.34225 > e158-093.eduroam.tugraz.ac.at.personal-agent: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 40
    0x0000:  4500 0044 68f8 4000 4011 25c6 8083 d0bf  E..Dh.@.@.%.....
    0x0010:  8083 da24 85b1 15b3 0030 148f 3132 3033  ...$.....0..1203
    0x0020:  3132 2e38 3336 3131 2c20 332c 2020 2d30  12.83611,.3,..-0
    0x0030:  2e31 3533 2c20 2d30 2e34 3630 2c20 2039  .153,.-0.460,..9
    0x0040:  2e39 3630                                .960
20:06:57.188105 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 26873, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 68)
    e108-193.eduroam.tugraz.ac.at.34225 > e158-093.eduroam.tugraz.ac.at.personal-agent: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 40
    0x0000:  4500 0044 68f9 4000 4011 25c5 8083 d0bf  E..Dh.@.@.%.....
    0x0010:  8083 da24 85b1 15b3 0030 1b80 3132 3033  ...$.....0..1203
    0x0020:  3132 2e38 3836 3135 2c20 332c 2020 2d30  12.88615,.3,..-0
    0x0030:  2e31 3533 2c20 2d30 2e33 3036 2c20 2039  .153,.-0.306,..9
    0x0040:  2e38 3037                                .807                                 
20:06:57.200719 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 26874, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 68)
    e108-193.eduroam.tugraz.ac.at.34225 > e158-093.eduroam.tugraz.ac.at.personal-agent: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 40
    0x0000:  4500 0044 68fa 4000 4011 25c4 8083 d0bf  E..Dh.@.@.%.....
    0x0010:  8083 da24 85b1 15b3 0030 2884 3132 3033  ...$.....0(.1203
    0x0020:  3132 2e39 3336 3135 2c20 332c 2020 2030  12.93615,.3,...0
    0x0030:  2e31 3533 2c20 2d30 2e31 3533 2c20 2039  .153,.-0.153,..9
    0x0040:  2e38 3037                                .807
```

and I need to convert it to this or similar shape:

```
20:06:57.049686  26871, 120312.78606,.0.153,.-0.153,..9.960
20:06:57.113591  26872, 120312.83611,-0.153,.-0.460,..9.960
20:06:57.188105  26873, 120312.88615,-0.153,.-0.306,..9.807
20:06:57.200719  26874, 120312.93615,.0.000,.-0.153,..9.807
```

So far a vb script was doing the job just fine, but now we need this data to be displayed live, so there has to be a script that will use grep/cut/awk whatever commands to do this as the log is being updated, hence the opening the file when its completed and using the vbscript in libre-office is not good anymore.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the vbscript might actually be broken. If you look the last block there gets you a `0.000` in field 3 which breaks with the pattern of output for every other block. My suspicion is that this occurs because you reference that val as a float and attempt to assign it the data on the right which - and only in the last block - is prefaced with a `(` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rethought my approach and decided using `H`old space was both easier and more robust. As you mention the file delimits on tabs rather than spaces the simple fix is to use a character class rather than the literal space character. The thing about classes though is they can tend to get a little bulky, and so I generally prefer to wrap them in a substitution when I use them. I'll also pack it up into a single simple command by wrapping it in a shell function.

Here it is again, different again:

```
#!/bin/sh
robot() (s=[:blank:];LC_ALL=C \
    sed "s/^[$s].*[$s]//;s/\.\.*/./g
    /[$s][^i$]*[^1-9d]*[d$s]*/!{H;\$!d
    };   s//,/;x;s///;s/\n//g
         s/,\.\([-1-9]*\)0*//
         s//,\1/g;s//,+.\1/g" "$@" 
)
robot "$@"
```

If the top and bottom line is removed from the above, it can be copy/pasted into a running POSIX-compatible shell that includes a POSIX-compatible `sed` in `$PATH`. Else the above above can be written verbatim to an executable file in `$PATH`. Either way, I can call it just like `INPUT| robot` or `robot <infile` or `robot infile1 infile[2-9] -`. Like:

```
robot <<\DATA
20:06:57.049686 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 26871, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 68)
    e108-193.eduroam.tugraz.ac.at.34225 > e158-093.eduroam.tugraz.ac.at.personal-agent: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 40
    0x0000:  4500 0044 68f7 4000 4011 25c7 8083 d0bf  E..Dh.@.@.%.....
    0x0010:  8083 da24 85b1 15b3 0030 1e8b 3132 3033  ...$.....0..1203
    0x0020:  3132 2e37 3836 3036 2c20 332c 2020 2030  12.78606,.3,...0
    0x0030:  2e31 3533 2c20 2d30 2e31 3533 2c20 2039  .153,.-0.153,..9
    0x0040:  2e39 3630                                .960
DATA
```

Whereas the older version printed...

```
20:06:57.049686,26871,.0.120312.78606,.3,.0.153,-0.153,.9.960
```

This one prints...

```
20:06:57.049686,26871,120312.78606,+.153,-.153,9.960
```

It now strips leading *.dots* or *0zeroes* from the various fields and removes the spurious `.3` field it got before that was not included in your output. It also adds `+` signs to even the output for fields that might lead with a *-dash*.

Maybe it does too much - I don't honestly know how all of those fields should come together and this only amounts to my best guess. I try to break it down below, but if you'd like to see it do something different for any reason don't hesitate to ask.

The character class `[:blank:]` matches any horizontal whitespace character as defined by locale - and so it can be a space or a tab and it will make no difference. And thinking about the locale I decided to explicitly specify the `C` locale here as it is always the most sensible thing to do when doing text processing - in the `C` locale each input byte is guaranteed to match a single character *(which can mean a whole lot to `sed` when it does stuff like `.*`)*. Any state defined in the function is local to the function only, though, and will not affect the execution environment except to print to `stdout`.

#### FLOW:

In the first line of the script `sed` will remove a sequence of characters from the first through last occurring `[[:blank:]]` *if* the line begins with one. It then also replaces any series of `.dot`s with a single `.dot`.

The next line is a little hairy. It is a single address fashioned to handle multiply staged `s///`ubstitutions using an empty address to refer to the last non-empty in the script.

```
/[$s][^i$]*[^d1-9]*[d$s]*/
```

The only *definite* match in the address is at least one blank - all other sequences within match *zero`*` or more occurrences* - and so it cannot match a line which contains no blanks at all. This means that it only matches block headings because we just removed all of the blanks from any line beginning with one.

So the first thing I do is compare it against non-header lines and place them in `H`old space if they do `!`not match it and `$!d`elete all of those that are `!`not the `$`last from output. And so the `$`last line here falls through to be lumped in with all block headings for the remainder of the script, because, from here on, those are the only lines to which `sed` will apply any rules.

Consider that address compared to a header line:

```
20:06:57.049686 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 26871, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 68)
```

- `[$s]` - matches the first blank - just before `IP`.
- `[^i$]*` - matches up the `64,[[:blank:]]`.
- `[^d1-9]* - matches the` i`.
- `[d$s]*` - matches the `d` and the `[[:blank:]]`

So when I do `s//,/` all of that is replaced with a comma. This doesn't affect the last line which we just let fall through because it cannot match the leading `[[:blank:]]`. And even if it did, any change would be irrelevant because, for the last line, the only copy ever printed is that waiting for us in `H`old space which we only operate on following an e`x`change. Which is the next command - and applies universally - and so we're now working with a pattern space that looks something like...

```
20:06:57.049686,26871, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 6\
8)\n40\nE.Dh.@.@.%.\n.$.0.1203\n12.78606,.3,.0\n.153,.-0.153,.9\n.960$
```

...which is representative of the edits already applied to the previous block heading and all lines which have been `H`eld since - as you can see delimited with `\n`ewline escapes there.

Let's compare that again to our long address:

- `[$s]` - matches the first `[[:blank:]]` occurring immediately before `offset`.
- `[^i$]*` - matches all the way up to but not including the first occurring `$` character.
- `[^d1-9]*` - matches `.0.`.
- `[d$s]*` - matches nothing at all.

So, as before, `s///` wipes all of that out. After also removing all `\n`ewlines like `s/\n//g` and now pattern space looks like:

```
20:06:57.049686,26871,120312.78606,.3,.0.153,.-0.153,.9.960
```

...which is pretty much where the old version left it. But I was having fun with the recursive matches and so I added a little. You should not though, that, while I probably could make it better as I find holes in it this last bit is a thing probably better done in a second filter with a fresh script targeting the csv's. Still, it definitely works with the example input and probably will with more, but I thought I just might disclaim it anyway in case it doesn't or in case it does but does not conform to your expectiations. The last two lines can easily be removed to obtain output in line with that which you accepted when you checked this answer - as shown above.

```
s/,\.\([-1-9]*\)0*//
```

That removes the first occurring sequence of a *,comma* followed by a *.dot*, then zero or more *-dash* or numbers which are not zero and any trailing zeroes. That gets the `,.3` field removed from output.

Applied a second time with a `g`lobal flag and saving the `\1` from being removed like `s//,\1/` and it transforms:

```
20:06:57.049686,26871,120312.78606,.0.153,.-0.153,.9.960
```

...into...

```
20:06:57.049686,26871,120312.78606,.153,-.153,9.960
```

One more time applied `g`lobally with an added `+.` like `s//,+./g` and it further modifies pattern space to read:

```
20:06:57.049686,26871,120312.78606,+.153,-.153,9.960
```

...which is what is then auto-printed to `stdout` before `sed` begins the next line cycle.

*if any reader has actually made it this far and is curious about what I mean by the old version, you'll find it and a detailed explanation of how it works in the edit history*

Feeding this script your entire example input gets:

```
20:06:57.049686,26871,120312.78606,+.153,-.153,9.960
20:06:57.113591,26872,120312.83611,-.153,-.460,9.960
20:06:57.188105,26873,120312.88615,-.153,-.306,9.807
20:06:57.200719,26874,120312.93615,+.153,-.153,9.807
```

Comment: it works for one line, but if instead of the data in the command I feed the file I get different things the reason is that that I have tabs instead of spaces e.g. '-TAB-0x0000:'

Comment: @ArobotfromMars - Yeah - that would explain a lot. To make it a little more robust, you can also employ the shell. I like to do it in a function. I'll do an update in a moment to show you.

Comment: @ArobotfromMars - ok. I put up a modified version that will handle whitespace of any kind gracefully.

Comment: ok, I am trying robot() (s=[:blank:];LC_ALL=C \
    sed "s/^[$s].*[$s]//;s/\.\.*/./g
    /[$s][^i$]*[^1-9d]*[d$s]*/!{H;\$!d
    };   s//,/;x;s///;s/\n//g
         s/,\.\([-1-9]*\)0*//
         s//,\1/g;s//,+.\1/g" "$@" )



<<\DATA (the data there)
DATA

echo $DATA -----and it comes out totally blank. I went through your logic and it seems sound. But I am trying to understand why it deletes it all! Maybe I will try to debug it somehow.

Comment: @ArobotfromMars - because of `echo "$data"` - what is that? This doesn't set any variables. You need to ensure that you format the heredocs properly - they must be delimited with newlines. But you don't have to use heredocs - you can just feed it your file.

Comment: I must be doing something totally wrong. I did feed my file, <input and I had >output, but the output was of zero length. .eg. './robot.sh <input >output' where robot.sh is the 'robot()(...)' function.@mikeserv

Comment: @ArobotfromMars - the `.sh` thing might be the problem. This is a function. And so, if you were to put it in a script file, because this is only a function definition statement, it would also need to be called from within the script like `robot() (.....); robot` - are you doing that? You can test this theory at your command line like `PROMPT:$ ( . ./robot.sh; robot <input )`. I wrote it so it can be copied and pasted exactly as is into your terminal and then ran like `PROMPT:$ robot <input` - it doesn't need a file necessarily - because it defines a new command.

Comment: @ArobotfromMars - I made a little edit which will hopefully make it clearer what I mean.

Comment: problem solved, I run it in dash and it works just fine! I was trying the default ubuntu terminal and the appropriate alterations to run it but I was only making it worse. Thank you for your time to look in to this. I would like to quote this solution in my report, so if you would like, you can send me some details to quote you properly other than just pointing to this url. @mikeserv

Comment: @ArobotfromMars - sure. I'm kinda proud of it actually - I wrote this while doing a similar thing for myself to serialize some data - much of the concepts fell together. That whole staged address thing is a bit of a first for me - learned it while writing this - I have been using empty addresses for quite a while, but I never stopped to consider that the same pattern can mean different things depending on what's come before. Anyway, I'm me at gmail if you want to send me an email.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - regarding my last comment here... We once had a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16859/discussion-between-mikeserv-and-stephane-chazelas) about `//` and, now that I think about it, I think you may have been trying to show me that these sorts of backwards-applications were possible with empty addresses then, but I *(characteristically)* failed to understand it at the time. Is this the kind of the thing you were talking about?